# What is the preferred way of saying "I have to go"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, modismos

## English

As far as I can tell there are two ways to say, "I have to go."

> 1. Tengo que ir.
> 2. Tengo ir.

Is the second way even right?  And if so, which one is the preferred way to say, "I have to go"?

---

## Español

Hasta este momento, entiendo que existen dos formas de decir "I have to go."

> 1. Tengo que ir.
> 2. Tengo ir.

La segunda forma es tan siquiera correcta? Si lo es, cuál es preferentemente la forma de decir "I have to go"?

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE, and thanks for the good question. We're glad you're here. :)

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I hope that this website will help me improve my Spanish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope; there are more ways:

- Me tengo que ir
- Yo me tengo que ir
- Tendré que ir
- Tendré que irme
- Me iré ahora

The exact translation of "I have to go" is "Yo tengo que ir", but that is not so correct:

I have to go on/this Sunday:

> Yo tengo que ir el/este domingo

I have to go now:

> - Me tengo que ir | Yo tengo que irme | <= without using now
> - Me tengo que ir ahora | Yo tengo que ir ahora <= using now

I hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome.  All the answers I wanted to know that I was too lazy to ask in class.

Comment: If you want to make the difference... ask in class :)

Answer (score 4):

In case you are leaving someone, I would say:

> Tengo que irme

Answer (score 0):

Do you have specific place you need to go? Without the reflexive, it may only makes sense with a particular destination, like *“Tengo que ir al médico mañana,”* or rather more rarely perhaps if you’re making a progressive tense, like *“Tengo que ir cantando toda la noche,”* as might be the case if you were in a *tuna*.

Otherwise, a reflexive *“Tengo que irme”* makes more sense, if what you mean is that you have to leave somewhere.

I guess there’s also *“Tengo que mear”*, but that’s a difference sense of “having to go”.  And you probably don’t want to make that one reflexive.  :)